# MongoDb Find() FullScan with Index

Tags: c#, mongodb

In mongo db

```
> show dbs
admin   (empty)
data    23.9423828125GB
local   (empty)
```

I have a table with an index:

```
> db.XXX.count();
80089670
```

C#:

```
voteCol.EnsureIndex("({ YYY:1 })");
```

When I am doing a query with the C# driver:

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> voteCol = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("XXX");
var query = new QueryDocument("YYY", DataUtils.getItemInPollIdList());
MongoCursor<BsonDocument> cursor =      voteCol.Find(query).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("ZZZ")).SetLimit(10).SetSkip(20);
```

The execution time for this part of the code is close to 0.

Then when I am trying to get the size of the cursor

```
cursor.Size();
```

I get a timeout.

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond.

In Mongo log

> Mon Aug 22 10:08:50 [conn9] query data.XXX ntoreturn:1 reslen:36
>   nscanned:80089670 { YYY: "1482092" }  nreturned:0 48935ms

What can it be? When the query is really executed? Why I can't get the results?

Edit 1: Added new index

> Mon Aug 22 10:17:38 [conn12] building new index on { ({ YYY:-1 }): 1 }
>   for data.XXX
>
> ```
>             4000000/80089670        4%
>             7866400/80089670        9%
>             11403000/80089670       14%
>             15000000/80089670       18%
>             19000000/80089670       23%
>             22988600/80089670       28%
>             26454700/80089670       33%
>             30000000/80089670       37%
>             33438600/80089670       41%
>             37000000/80089670       46%
>             40810600/80089670       50%
>             44132200/80089670       55%
>             48000000/80089670       59%
>             52000000/80089670       64%
>             55618300/80089670       69%
>             59000000/80089670       73%
>             62170100/80089670       77%
>             66000000/80089670       82%
>             70000000/80089670       87%
>             74000000/80089670       92%
>             77874500/80089670       97%
> ```

Even with the new index - same issue:
Mongo shell:

```
> printjson(db.XXX.findOne({YYY:"1517077"}));
```

MongoLog

```
Mon Aug 22 10:33:40 [conn4] query data.XXX ntoreturn:1 reslen:36 nscanned:80089670 { YYY: "1517077" }  nreturned:0 48751ms
```

Comment: It scanned 80 millions of documents, it takes a lot of time)

Comment: @Hohhi Why? I added an index. Can you explain the full scan?

Comment: this is what it wrote in log: nscanned:80089670

Comment: probably the index is ascending and you've set it up descending

Comment: @Hohhi - I know but how can it be? did I missed something? If we have an index - even if the table is huge the access time should be on O(1) no?

Comment: try something like:voteCol.EnsureIndex("({ YYY:-1 })");

Comment: @Hohhi - pending... Ok. So what is the rule? why index should be ascending?

Comment: I thought of your code : SortBy.Descending("ZZZ") but know I think the problem is in something else

Comment: I think you should try querying your DB inside a client first and seeing if your index are created and work. And then experiment with the code. MongoVUE has a nice GUI

Comment: @Hohhi - same issue with the index (I edited the post)

Comment: try var query = Query.EQ("YYY", DataUtils.getItemInPollIdList()); instead of var query = new QueryDocument("YYY", DataUtils.getItemInPollIdList());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a mistake - all is case sensitive in mongoDb.

I added an index on `yyy` instead of `YYY`.

No warning message even if I have nothing named yyy in the table and the index was created successfully :(.

I recreated an index on the correct column name. Everything is fast now.

Answer (score 1):

the size of the cursor returns its size in bytes. What you should be interested in order to prevent all scans is the number of documents. Use this snippet:

```
collection.FindAll().Count();
```